# how can i install this nuget package?

Tags: nuget-package, barcode-scanner, maui

I'm having this error while installing a package, does anyone know how to fix it?

> Install-Package : Impossibile trovare una parte del percorso
> 'C:\Users\Sisinfo01.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.1\lib\xamarinios10\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\Headers\GoogleUtilitiesComponents-umbrella.h'.
> In riga:1 car:1

- Install-Package "C:\Users\Sisinfo01.nuget\packages\barcodescanner.mo ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
  ```

I tried to search on the internet but I can't find anything and actually the folder is missing the files but how can I fix it

Comment: What package are you using？ Is this package installed?https://www.nuget.org/packages/BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui/

Comment: yes exactly, but I can not install it in any way